# Figuring out a TestFlight crash report for a RubyMotion app

Tags: ios, rubymotion, testflight

I am looking at a crash report in TestFlight for my Ruby Motion app ("Habits") and it's giving me this:

```
undefined method `active' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) 
2 Habits 0x004bd2f3 rb_rb2oc_exc_handler + 163
3 Habits 0x0003a38b main (main.mm:20)...
```

How do I figure out which line of Ruby code triggered this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running into the same problem... check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/1740868

And this blog post:

http://nofail.de/2013/09/omg-apple-rejected-my-app/

Basically you would do something like this:

`$ xcrun atos -arch armv7 -o Habits.app 0x004bd2f3`

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost just as confused as you on this, but I can at least post my assumption? I'm assuming you can't figure out which line of code triggered this because it looks as though the caught error itself doesn't know its origin: `nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`.

To me, it appears that the method `active` is trying to be called from a class which hasn't been defined or has no specific memory thus being `NilClass`.

I may be completely off base here, but that's my insight.

Comment: Hi, I'm not asking for help figuring out the specific error - I'm trying to figure out exactly how to get the crash report to point at the right line in my Ruby source file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't uploaded a .dSYM file along with your build.

Without a .dSYM file, Testflight, or any other iOS crash reporting system, won't be able to connect the dots between the compiled code and your source files.

To get symbolicated crash reports (including file names / line numbers), you'll need to upload a .dSYM file along with your build file.

You can view TestFlight's documentation for including a .dSYM file either manually or with their Desktop app here:

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829888-uploading-a-dsym-with-a-build-

There is also a RubyMotion gem that handles [that process](https://github.com/HipByte/motion-testflight/blob/master/lib/motion/project/testflight.rb#L122) for you via a rake task:

https://github.com/HipByte/motion-testflight

I've been happily using this gem in my projects.

Comment: The reported stack trace **is** already symbolicated but is missing any valuable information. This doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded a dSYM but I think perhaps I needed to do it via the testflight-motion gem instead of using the TestFlight App. I'll do that in future but in the meantime I'm wondering if there's any way to make sense of the current data up there. E.g. what is the +163 relative to here? Do I have enough information to get back to the Ruby code?